# Express ∅ using only A, ∗ and parentheses (if necessary).

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

We define the operation $∗$ on subsets of a universal set $U$ as follows. For any two sets $A$ and $B$:

$$A * B := A^c  ∪ B^c$$

Express $∅$ using only $A$, $*$ and parentheses (if necessary).

So here's what I've done:

$∅ = A ∩ A^c$

$= A ∩ (A^c ∪ A^c)$

$= A ∩ (A * A)$

$= (A ∩ A) * (A ∩ A)$

$= A * A$

Is my derivation correct?

Comment: Is $\cap$ distributative over * ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true in general that $\varnothing = A\star A$, in fact $A\star A$ equals the complement of $A$, which is non-empty in general. However, you may observe that $A\star(A\star A)$ equals the entire space, by substituting the result of my first sentence into the definition of $\star$.

Thus, we can get the empty set by taking two copies of this "triple" set as follows:
$$
(A\star(A\star A))\star(A\star(A\star A))=\varnothing.
$$

Comment: This makes sense. How do I get $(A * (A * A))$ from $A ∩ (A * A)$?

Comment: @investigate311 you don't. $(A \ast (A \ast A))=X$ as was explained.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing: https://i.imgur.com/ihjKp9Y.png

Answer (score 0):

$A*A=A^c \cup A^c=A^c \ne \phi$

$(A*A^c)^c=(A^c\cup A)^c=U^c=\phi$

Your mistake was in the fourth line of your derivation, $A\cap (A*A)=A\cap (A^c\cup A^c)= (A\cap A^c)\cup (A\cap A^c) \ne (A\cap A)*(A\cap A)$

Comment: Note that this does not answer the question, since complement is not in the list of allowed operations - only $A,\star,$ and parentheses. See my answer for a solution.

Comment: You're right my answer is wrong then. I am sorry